# PHP problems after moving codeigniter system to Amazon AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, cpanel

I have a problem after moving a system I made with codeigniter 3, I did all the development on inmotionhosting VPS and all works 100% with cpanel, but the client purchased an AWS (Amazon Web Services) and after moving all everything just like in inmotionhosting, a lot of problems started, many PHP errors showed up (syntaxis, unexpected tokens, unexpected end of files), json enconde not working with php requests, this is the both php infos, both are running under php 7.0, I'm not server administrator so im not sure if both versions aren't the same, or something need to be changed

Amazon Web Services PHP Info (Not working)

http://consultas.academia.org.mx/phpinfo.php

Inmotion Hosting PHP Info (Working)

https://consultasacademia.org.mx/phpinfo.php

**EDIT:**

Example of code that works in inmotion and not working on amazon, in amazon is unexpected token >, there is like 100 errors like this in different parts of the code

```
<?
if($consulta->previo){
echo $consulta->previo;
}else{
?>
```

I'll appreciate any help

Thanks!

Comment: you need to tell us what the actual problems are

Comment: i did added a simple example of a code that works in inmotion and not working on amazon

Comment: i thought "unexpected token" was a javascript error not a php one

Comment: not certain, but seems to me your `short_open_tag` should be set 'On' on amazon.  This in one of many many settings and build options that you will need to examine carefully and test for. Remember, you change a setting, you restart your web server AND php-fpm

Comment: the unexpected token its because is on a json var

Comment: What you are experiencing is exactly why using PHP's short open tags is always bad idea since it hinders the portability of your code:  Set `short_open_tag=On` in your php.ini file and restart Apache and PHP-FPM